# Using Windows Storage Server for other things

Tags: windows, windows-storage-server

Are there any reasons not to use Windows Storage Server for other minor things such as running a 3rd party service or application that requires a lot of storage?  The reason I ask is because I have a Windows Storage Server that is being used for this purpose.  We decided to also run a SVN server & very low use mysql server on it.  It has been running great.  I'm planning on getting a new one soon & I'm just wondering if there's something verboten about using Windows Storage Server for anything other than SAN/NAS duties?  My understanding is that the Storage Server part just adds some software on top of Windows Server that adds some storage specific functionality to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost positive that WSS isn't licensed for use by non-OEMs. It is only supported by Microsoft Partners that create storage solutions for integration into their storage devices.

It wasn't meant for roll-your-own solutions. Because of this, I wouldn't recommend doing **anything** with it, including running your organization's storage.

Comment: This isn't at all correct. The only way to purchase WSS is on OEM hardware; there is no way to buy a license and install it on your own hardware. As such, buying a WSS appliance and using it is totally fine. To answer your original question, running light-weight apps on it is just fine. [See here for more info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/storageserver/archive/2014/12/10/windows-storage-server-2012-r2-essentials-a-closer-look.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted answer isn't at all correct](https://serverfault.com/a/317330/118258). The only way to purchase WSS is on OEM hardware; there is no way to buy a license and install it on your own hardware. As such, buying a WSS appliance and using it is totally fine.

To answer your original question, running light-weight apps on it is just fine.

[See here for more info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/storageserver/archive/2014/12/10/windows-storage-server-2012-r2-essentials-a-closer-look.aspx).